# Frame error on Primary NIC

Tags: networking, nic

I have a 25 Node Cloudera cluster and on all the nodes i am getting critical warning

```
Network frame errors account for 0.95 of incoming network packets over the past 15 minute(s) across all monitored network interfaces. Critical threshold: 0.50%
```

I searched on Net and this is related to NIC on which they are working but i could't resolve the problem as i don't know the root cause

Below is the output on ifconfig

```
 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:eb:c5:a7
      inet addr:192.X.X.X  Bcast:192.X.X.Y  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:feeb:c5a7/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:361764563 errors:503994 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:503994
      TX packets:885327394 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:184606487706 (184.6 GB)  TX bytes:859026289443 (859.0 GB)
```

All i can see is an error in RX and same number in is frame.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely source of these errors is cabling. As a first step I would try a different cable between your server and the switch. Also, check all the connectors, try to unplug and plug them back, try different ports on the switch.

Comment: Thanks @dtoubelis i will do that and let you know if it works out.

Comment: @VikasHardia, this is quite common problem when you run 1Gbps over old CAT5 cables - ports may sync at 1Gbps but you will be getting lots of frame errors.